Why does the nested sterilizer in django rest framework not work?
Good afternoon, I'm making an API and I ran into a problem, the embedded sterilizer does not work.
Models
from django.db import models

def upload_to(instance, filename):
return 'posts/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

class Brands (models.Model):
    BrandsDescription=models.TextField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.BrandsDescription[0:50]

class Cosmetic (models.Model):
    CosmeticName = models.TextField(default="")
    CosmeticDescription = models.TextField(null=True)
    Price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    UrlsImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, default = "")
    IsItNew = models.BooleanField(default="")
    Brands = models.ForeignKey(Brands,related_name="brands", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.CosmeticName[0:50]

class Order (models.Model):
    UserToken = models.TextField(default="")
    Date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Product = models.ManyToManyField(Cosmetic)
    Price = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['UserToken']

def __str__(self):
    return self.UserToken[0:50]

Serializers
from dataclasses import field
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class BrandsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Brands
        fields='__all__'

class CosmeticSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    brands=BrandsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model= Cosmetic
        fields=('CosmeticName','CosmeticDescription','Price','UrlsImage','IsItNew','brands')

class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product = CosmeticSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model= Order
        fields=('UserToken','Date','product','Price')

class postOrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Order
        fields='__all__'

Views
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import *
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from api.permissions import IsAdminOrReadOnly
from .serializers import *
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
class BrandsAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Brands.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandsSerializer

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
       return Response(data)



class CosmeticAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Cosmetic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CosmeticSerializer

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
       return Response(data)


class OrderAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    search_fields = ['UserToken']

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
       return Response(data)

class PostOrderAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class= postOrderSerializer

result


You don't need a sterilizer, but a serializer...

You confused many things. Let's start by your models.
Inside your models Cosmetics, you have a field named Brands, which is a ForeignKey to the models Brands, you set the related name to brands. This means the from an instance of Brands you can access all the Cosmetic which are linked to this instance of Brands. So a non confusing related_name can cosmetics.
Now let's jump in the serializers.
In the CosmeticSerialiers you created a field named brand which is embedded serializer to BrandsSerializer, but it's totally wrong. Each cosmetic only has one brand linked to it.
If you want to do what you want, it's in the BrandsSerializer where you can add fields
brands = CosmeticSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

For OrderSerializer, the problem is that you have a typo in the field name.
In the model Order, the ManyToMany field is Product, but in the OrderSerializer, the field on which you set embedding serializer CosmeticSerializer is product. The capital letter changes all, this means that it's a brand new field you created in OrderSerializer.
What I recommand you is to follow PEP for your naming convention.

Variables, functions and fields name: snake_case
Class names: PascalCase

